# Null-homotopies in the space of framed functions on a surface

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, morse-theory

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold.  Morse functions on $M$ are smooth functions $M \to \mathbb{R}$ with only very nice singularities.

> **Fact:** The space of Morse functions on $M$ is not, in general, connected.

The space of "generalized Morse functions" includes Morse functions and those with slightly worse singularities.

> **Theorem:** (Cerf?) The space of generalized Morse functions on $M$ *is* connected.

But the space of generalized Morse functions is not, in general, simply-connected.  So there are loops in the space of Morse functions which are homotopically non-trivial.

Finally, there is the space of "framed functions" on $M$.  Let $f$ be a smooth function which has only reasonable singularities.  A framing on $f$ is a smooth choice of frame for the negative eigenspace of the Hessian of $f$ at each of its singular points.

> **Theorem**: ([Igusa](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1987-301-02/S0002-9947-1987-0882699-7/)) The space of framed functions on an $n$-dimensional manifold is $(n-1)$-connected.

So for a surface, the space of framed functions is simply-connected.  One ought to be able to find a loop of generalized Morse functions on a closed surface which is not contractible in the space of generalized Morse functions but which is contractible in the space of framed functions (after adding framing data).

My question is: **are standard examples known to experts?**  Are they available anywhere in the literature?

(Thanks to [Lurie](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0465), as well as [Eliashberg and Mishachev](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1000v1), we know that the space of framed functions on a manifold is in fact contractible, but understanding $\pi_1$ seems like a good first goal.)

---

Word on the street is that the following is a good candidate, so I'll include it in case it jogs someone's memory.  The manifold at hand is $S^2$.  The diagrams below each show (schematically) a Morse function on $S^2$ with three $2$-handles, two $1$-handles, and a single $0$-handle.  Each diagram has three circles (representing the $2$-handles) and two arcs (the cores of the $1$-handles).   So the index two critical points lie above your screen and the index one and zero critical points lie below it.

The diagram shows a sequence of three handleslides between the 1-handles.  The last function is of course isotopic through Morse functions to the first.

> **Rumor:** This loop of Morse functions is not contractible in the space of generalized Morse functions.  After endowing the one-handles with framings (i.e. orienting the arcs) this path is no longer a loop, but the path given by traversing it twice is a loop and is contractible!
>
> [image]

Comment: The standard example of a non-trivial loop in the space of generalized Morse functions which is no longer a loop after adding framings is the swallowtail move. This starts with a single index i critical point, then introduces a canceling i and (i-1) pair of crit. points, and finally cancels the original i critical point and the new (i-1), leaving a single index i critical point behind. It is show in Figure B in section 1 of Igusa's paper "The Space of Framed Functions".